# Best way to add python scripting into QT application?

Tags: c++, python, qt

I have a QT 4.6 application (C++ language) and i need to add python scripting to it on windows platform. Unfortunately, i never embed python before, and it seems to be a lot of different ways to do so. Can anyone share his wisdom and point me into some articles/documentation i can read to perform a specified task in less painful way?

Comment: If you're properly abstracting your design, the QTness shouldn't be relevant. Might help simplify your problem with one less thing to think about. :)

Comment: Yes, i know, but i'm mentioning QT so if it's some good articles exists that are QT-specific, or some binding available, i can use it instead of pure abstract way ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:**

You can use PythonQt (not PyQt) that allow you to use Python with Qt. I think this is what you are searching for.

Here a documentation on the official website: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-pythonqt.html.

Comment: PyQt and PythonQt are two very different projects. PyQt lets you write Qt apps in Python. PythonQt lets you embed a Python interpreter inside a C++ Qt app.

Answer (score 7):

You should take a look at [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/). From the homepage:

> PythonQt is a dynamic [Python](http://www.python.org)
>   binding for [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). It offers
>   an easy way to embed the Python
>   scripting language into your Qt
>   applications. It makes heavy use of
>   the QMetaObject system and thus
>   requires Qt4.x. In contrast to PyQt ,
>   PythonQt is not a complete Python
>   wrapper around the complete Qt
>   functionality. So if you are looking
>   for a way to write complete
>   applications in Python using the Qt
>   GUI, you should use PyQt.
>
> If you are looking for a simple way to
>   embed Python objects into your C++/Qt
>   Application and to script parts of
>   your application via Python, PythonQt
>   is the way to go!

Build/installation instructions for Windows is near the bottom of the page.

Comment: Where is a windows installer? I can only see sources?

Comment: Sorry. There is no windows installer, as I'd remembered. You can install Python from the python.org installer, but you need VS to build PythonQt; I updated my answer.