# Is PythonQt deprecated?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I have a C++ application that I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2010 that needs to be able to call a couple python scripts and read their output, but I can't count on Python being installed on the computer. [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the favored simple option, but [every](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908269/best-way-to-add-python-scripting-into-qt-application) post I've seen is dated 2009 or older. [The main tutorial](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-pythonqt.html) even still says TrollTech on it.

This makes me think that this methodology/class is dated or perhaps deprecated. Is boost::Python the way to go now, or does PythonQt still do the trick, or should I just [embed Python the normal C++ way](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) like everyone else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PythonQt is under active development, PythonQt 3.0 with Qt 5 and Python 3 support has just been released. Have a look at the [PythonQt project page at Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonqt/).

Answer (score 3):

`PythonQt` is still alive and it's philosophy is much more different than the other two components `PySide` and `PyQt`.

The other thing is that `Florian` efforts of supporting the community is very valuable and he keeps the component update as necessary.

It also does do it's job perfect and you can call a `Python` function from `C++` or call a `C++` function from `Python` and I don't think there would be any more requirements in many of the applications.

Comment: Is it a bit saddenning to have different components named "PythonQt" and "PyQt", because then you have questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269936/python-qt-progressbar where the title is "PythonQt" while it is really is about "PyQt"...

Comment: unfortunately there is not many options for a meaningful name for these kinda components, you have to set a meaningful name that consists of "python" and "qt" abbreviations, so it happens, but they ARE different.

Answer (score -2):

I thought `PySide` is a future of Qt on Python and PythonQt will be deprecated a loooong time ago.

On PythonQt svn repo was just 11 commits from start of the 2013 year and PySide latest release was just few months ago. So, I'd use PySide and say 'PythonQt is dead' rather than use PythonQt. That's all I can say. Hope it helps.

Comment: PySide is going the wrong way. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought that the PythonQt library was for calling Python functions from a C++-based Qt program, while PySide and PyQt were all about using Qt from python.